# using roslyn, how to get a type of 'var'?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, roslyn-project-system

[image]

I want to get the type represented by `var`.

```cs
var localDeclaration = methodDeclaration.DescendantNodes().OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>().First();
var identifierName = localDeclaration.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().First();
var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifierName);
var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(identifierName).Type;
```

I tried `GetSymbolInfo()` and `GetTypeInfo()`, the first one returns `null`, the second one returns `{?}`.

[Get Type of 'var' with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878120/get-type-of-var-with-roslyn)
The method it provides does not work either. The debugging information is attached in the figure below. You can see that these values are all null or {?}.
[image]

My code looks like this

```
public class Start
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitEnvironment();
        Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void InitEnvironment()
    {
        GlobalVariable.MySolution = MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenSolutionAsync(ConstVariable.SolutionPath).Result;
        GlobalVariable.MyProject = GlobalVariable.MySolution.Projects.First(x => x.Name == "GamePlay");
        GlobalVariable.CompilationByAll = GlobalVariable.MyProject.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
    }

    private static void Run()
    {
        var tree = SyntaxTreeProcessor.GetSyntaxTreeByFileName(ConstVariable.SystemPath + @"\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs");
        var semanticModel = GlobalVariable.CompilationByAll.GetSemanticModel(tree);
        var methodDeclarations = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();
        foreach(var methodDeclaration in methodDeclarations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"methodDeclaration:{methodDeclaration.Identifier.ValueText}");
            var localDeclaration = methodDeclaration.DescendantNodes().OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>().First();
            var identifierName = localDeclaration.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().First();
            foreach (var varibale in localDeclaration.Declaration.Variables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"varibale.Identifier:{varibale.Identifier}");
                Console.WriteLine($"varibale.Initializer:{varibale.Initializer}");
            }
            var variableType = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(localDeclaration.Declaration.Type).Symbol;
            var typeSymbol = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(identifierName).Type;
            var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifierName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(tree.FilePath);
    }
}
```

I tried the Syntax Visualizer tool in visual studio 2019 and it showed the correct type.
[image]

[image]

The result of GetDiagnostic() is as follows:

```
COUNT:  32
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (0,6)-(0,12)未能找到类型或命名空间名“System”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (1,6)-(1,12)未能找到类型或命名空间名“System”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (2,6)-(2,12)未能找到类型或命名空间名“System”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (3,6)-(3,12)未能找到类型或命名空间名“System”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (6,6)-(6,13)未能找到类型或命名空间名“Entitas”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (10,111)-(10,128)未能找到类型或命名空间名“IInitializeSystem”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (14,15)-(14,19)预定义类型“System.Void”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (20,54)-(20,60)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (20,54)-(20,60)未能找到类型或命名空间名“Entity”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (20,79)-(20,97)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (20,27)-(20,31)预定义类型“System.Void”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (12,16)-(12,41)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (16,24)-(16,32)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (16,24)-(16,32)当前上下文中不存在名称“GetWorld”
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (17,60)-(17,85)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (22,24)-(22,32)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (22,24)-(22,32)当前上下文中不存在名称“GetWorld”
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (23,12)-(23,42)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (23,53)-(23,83)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (23,53)-(23,83)预定义类型“System.Void”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (24,65)-(24,95)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (24,97)-(24,101)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (24,97)-(24,101)未能找到类型或命名空间名“Game”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (26,45)-(26,75)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (26,77)-(26,81)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (26,77)-(26,81)未能找到类型或命名空间名“Game”(是否缺少 using 指令或程序集引用?)
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (32,12)-(32,30)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (34,16)-(34,107)预定义类型“System.Boolean”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (38,16)-(38,30)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (38,31)-(38,40)预定义类型“System.Object”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (38,16)-(38,47)预定义类型“System.Boolean”未定义或导入
I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs: (40,20)-(40,111)预定义类型“System.Boolean”未定义或导入
methodDeclaration:Initialize
varibale.Identifier:world
varibale.Initializer:= GetWorld()

methodDeclaration:HandleReliableRequest
varibale.Identifier:world
varibale.Initializer:= GetWorld()

I:\gameplay\Test\GamePlay\System\GameModeSystems\JokerMode\JokerProcessPlayerStatisSystems.cs
```

Comment: Did i do something wrong and what should i do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Type of 'var' with Roslyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878120/get-type-of-var-with-roslyn)

Comment: If you mean "in the question": nothing wrong I can see, except maybe replace that image with code (images are the absolute worst way to share code); interesting question, and the post GSerg links to may help - it sound like you e already tried GetSymbolInfo(), though

Comment: Yes, I tried my best to search for similar problems and try to solve them. But until now, I still don't know how to solve it.
I have added relevant debugging information and relatively complete code.

Comment: What does GlobalVariable.CompilationByAll().GetDiagnostics() return?

Comment: Judging from the result of GetDiagnostic(), the relevant definition is missing. These definitions exist in common.dll, how should I introduce it into my compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution. I put it here for people with the same confusion. If you have a better way, you are welcome to write it down below. thanks.

```
        private static void InitEnvironment()
        {
            GlobalVariable.MySolution = MSBuildWorkspace.Create().OpenSolutionAsync(ConstVariable.SolutionPath).Result;

            var metadataReferenceCustomDlls = Directory.GetFiles(@"I:\gameplay\Library\", "*.dll");
            var metadataReferences = metadataReferenceCustomDlls.Select(f => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(f)).ToList();
            var metadataReferenceNetStandardDlls = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\", "*.dll");
            var metadataReferencesB = metadataReferenceNetStandardDlls.Select(f => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(f)).ToList();
            metadataReferences = metadataReferences.Concat(metadataReferencesB).ToList();
            foreach (var projectId in GlobalVariable.MySolution.ProjectIds.ToArray())
            {
                GlobalVariable.MySolution = GlobalVariable.MySolution.AddMetadataReferences(projectId, metadataReferences);
            }

            GlobalVariable.MyProject = GlobalVariable.MySolution.Projects.First(x => x.Name == "GamePlay");
            GlobalVariable.CompilationByAll = GlobalVariable.MyProject.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
        }
```

I added some code in InitEnvironment().In general, the corresponding reference is added.